# How to grab the number and hashtag out of the quotes using R ? <hashtag count="5" value="#starbucks"/>

Tags: r, regex, stringr

```
[1] <hashtag count="5" value="#starbucks"/>   


    Count   Hashtags
[1] 5       #starbucks
```

The column I have now is in the one character in the brackets, how can I gent the number and text of the hashtag out and split into two columns?

Comment: Match `<hashtag(?=(?:[^>"']|"[^"]*"|'[^']*')*?\scount\s*=\s*(?:(['"])\s*([\S\s]*?)\s*\1))(?=(?:[^>"']|"[^"]*"|'[^']*')*?\svalue\s*=\s*(?:(['"])\s*\#([\S\s]*?)\s*\3))\s+(?:"[\S\s]*?"|'[\S\s]*?'|[^>]*?)+/>` The things you want are in group 2 and 4 respectively. And you can get this directly searching any web site source code.

Answer (score 2):

This seems to be a simple regex question:

```
library(stringr)
strings <- c('<hashtag count="5" value="#starbucks"/>',
             '<hashtag count="99" value="#peets coffee"/>')
str_match(strings, 'count=\\"(\\d+).*value=\\"#([^"]+)')[,2:3]

     [,1] [,2]          
[1,] "5"  "starbucks"   
[2,] "99" "peets coffee"
```

If strings is a data.frame, you'll need to `apply` the function by row and choose the correct column to extract the values from:

```
strings <- data.frame(str = c('<hashtag count="5" value="#starbucks"/>',
                              '<hashtag count="99" value="#peets coffee"/>'),
                      col2 = c(2,4))
apply(strings, 1, function(x) str_match(x['str'],
                                        'count=\\"(\\d+).*value=\\"#([^"]+)')[,2:3])
     [,1]        [,2]          
[1,] "5"         "99"          
[2,] "starbucks" "peets coffee"
```